# Chapter titles do not escape characters properly when a link is near a page break

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, chapters

Consider the following document (also on [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/read/vgkwgwjpnxzv)):

```latex
\documentclass{extbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

% Note the escaped hash sign
\chapter{\#1: Test}

\lipsum[1-3]

% Extra lines just to force the link over the page
Foo

Bar

Baz

\href{http://example.com}{Test}

\end{document}
```

The above document fails to compile, complaining:

```
You can't use `macro parameter character #' in horizontal mode.

<argument> ...{\Hy@tocdestname }{\numberline {1}##
                                                  ##1: Test}\hyper@linkend 
l.1 ...er}{\numberline {1}##1: Test}{3}{chapter.1}
```

This appears to happen when the `\href` is exactly one line down from the page break (you can see this by adding/removing paragraphs, or by removing the link altogether).

For some reason I can't work out, when the link is in *exactly* this position, the Table of Contents `.toc` file fails to correctly escape the `#` symbol in the chapter title.

Does anyone know why this happens, and how to correct it?

Comment: It looks like this also has something to do with the link being the first thing on the line. One potential—but exceptionally hacky—solution is to prepend the link with a zero-width-space: `\hspace{0pt}\href{...}{...}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Protect the hash (I don't know yet why the link makes it fragile):

```
\documentclass{extbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

% Note the escaped hash sign
\chapter{\protect\#1: Test}

\lipsum[1-3]

% Extra lines just to force the link over the page
Foo

Bar

Baz

\href{http://example.com}{Test}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Seems to work a treat - would be interesting to know why on earth an `href` does this, though

Comment: Well href does change the catcode of #, that is not surprising - # is a quite common symbol in an url, the main question is where in the output routine this clashes with the writing to the aux-file, and if the clash can be avoided.